# selecting where in php mysql if where is equals to array index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

hey guys im trying to query something in php but the WHERE is a index from array this is what i did

```
    $data=array();
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    $item = array(
                                       'sec_id'=>$row['section_id'],
                                       'sec_name'=>$row['section_name'],
                                       'sec_dept'=>$row['section_department'],
                                       'sec_lvl'=>$row['section_level'],
                                      'advisory_id'=>$row['advisory_id'],
                                      'first_name'=>$row['f_firstname'],
                                      'last_name'=>$row['f_lastname'],
                                      'middle_name'=>$row['f_middlename'],
                                      'advisor_id'=>$row['faculty_id'],
                                    );


                    $get_subjects = "SELECT subject_name
                                        FROM subjects  
                                        WHERE level = '".$row['section_level']."' ";


                        $result_get_subjects =mysql_query($get_subjects)or die(mysql_error());

                        $subjects_count = mysql_num_rows($result_get_subjects);


                    $check_archive_subjects = " SELECT b.subject_name 
                                                FROM registrar_grade_archive a
                                                LEFT JOIN subjects b ON(a.subject_id=b.subject_id)
                                                LEFT JOIN section c ON(a.section_id = c.section_id)                                                 
                                                WHERE a.advisor_faculty_id ='".$row['faculty_id']."'
                                                WHERE a.section_id ='".$row['section_id']."'

                                                GROUP BY b.subject_name ASC
                                                 " ;

                     $query_checking =mysql_query($check_archive_subjects)or die(mysql_error());

                    $subjects_count_sent = mysql_num_rows($query_checking);
```

but unfortunately i got an error in $check_archive_subjects that says:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE a.section_id ='24'
```

is there any other way to put an array index in where clause in mysql. I know mysql is deprecated and ill be switching to mysqli after i finished this project so pardon me guys. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple `WHERE` conditions should be joined using boolean keywords `AND` or `OR`. You don't issue multiple `WHERE` clauses.

Also, please read this regarding the MySQL extension - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/283366

Comment: oh!!.. silly me.. i thought it was the array. thanks! BTW i have read about that. Im still using mysql bcuz this is what our professors thought to us and lately i found out that its already deprecated when we already started this project.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT b.subject_name
FROM registrar_grade_archive a
LEFT JOIN subjects b ON(a.subject_id=b.subject_id)
LEFT JOIN section c ON(a.section_id = c.section_id)
WHERE a.advisor_faculty_id ='".$row['faculty_id']."' AND a.section_id ='".$row['section_id']."'
GROUP BY b.subject_name ASC
```

## Explanation

Using multiple `WHERE` clause like above is not accepted in MySQL. Try replacing the 2nd `WHERE` using an `AND` or using an `OR` depending on your requirement. I have used `AND`